# Getting wrong selection on an Array.sample Ruby

Tags: ruby, random

so I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to create a trivia game. I had a couple questions about it. Here is my current code.

```
  def random_question
    #Going to work a way to use a hash instead of two seperate arrays
    question_array = Array["Which state is known as the Evergreen State?", "What state is AZ?", "What state is CA?",
    'What state is known as the Last Frontier?']
    #random_question = question_array.shuffle.first
    $ind = question_array.find_index($rand)
    return $rand = question_array.sample
  end
  #If lives does not equal zero, let the game play out
  while lives != 0
    answer_array = Array["Washington", "Arizona", "California", "Alaska"]

    puts random_question()
    puts "!!!---" + $rand + "---!!!"
    puts "What is your answer?"
    #Takes answer(answer_response) and compares it to the correct answer
    answer_response = gets.chomp
    print answer_array[$ind.to_i - 1]
    if answer_response == answer_array[$ind.to_i - 1]
      puts "You're right!"
      points += 10
      puts "You have " + points.to_s + " points!"
    else
      puts "That is wrong. You lose a life!"
      lives -= 1
      puts "You have " + lives.to_s + " lives left!"
    end
```

Whenever I run this Ruby code in my CMD or Command Line, it spits out a totally random answer rather than the answer I would like it to display.

Does anyone have a solution? Or better yet, would anyone be able to tell me how to use a hash/dictionary where the question is linked to the answer? Please help. :)

Comment: Hint: are you using `$rand` before assigning it?

Comment: I guess I am, I noticed that. But I thought since it was a global variable it would work. Sorry, I'm kind of new to Ruby. But I will adjust that and see if anything changes. :)

Comment: I went ahead and did that @rogerdpack and it ended up throwing me an error stating. "states.rb:239:in `gameplay': undefined method `find_index' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from states.rb:269:in `<main>'"

Comment: The `gameplay` method is not shown here.

Comment: It would be easier for readers to follow your code if the rules of the trivia game were stated at the beginning of the question.

Comment: You'd want something like `$rand= question_array.sample; $ind =  question_array.find_index($rand); return $rand` also `$ind.to_i - 1` is probably off by one, since the index is the index, try `$ind` instead.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @rogerdpack, I really appreciate that. I will try that out right now. That would be a lot easier to follow. (Also, side note: I put in the $ind.to_i - 1 because I thought it was off by one. But after some testing, it was just spitting out random ones. So, I will go ahead and try that thank you! :)

Comment: Hey @CarySwoveland, I will take that into account while I go through it again. I will write in some rules and such. So, thank you. :)

Comment: @rogerdpack That worked wonders! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You did it, nice work!  Feel free to put the updated working code here as an answer and select your own answer in a few days, for followers...

Comment: Okay, I will go ahead and do that as soon as I get back to my laptop today. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to the help of @rogerdpack, I found an answer to my question last night. Here is the correct code written out. :)

```
def random_question
    #Going to work a way to use a hash instead of two seperate arrays
    $question_array = Array["Which state is known as the Evergreen State?", "What state is AZ?", "What state is CA?",
    'What state is known as the Last Frontier?']
    $rand= $question_array.sample;
    $ind = $question_array.find_index($rand);
    return $rand
    #random_question = question_array.shuffle.first
  end
  #If lives does not equal zero, let the game play out
  while lives != 0
    answer_array = Array["Washington", "Arizona", "California", "Alaska"]
    puts "---------------------"
    puts random_question()
    puts "---------------------"
    puts "What is your answer?"
    puts "---------------------"
    #Takes answer(answer_response) and compares it to the correct answer
    answer_response = gets.chomp
    if answer_response == answer_array[$ind]
      puts "You're right!"
      points += 10
      puts "You have " + points.to_s + " points!"
    else
```

So thanks a ton to everyone who helped out, but this code is working out correctly and the way I would like.